# Flipping images using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am familiarizing myself with the software called 'MATLAB' and I have the file called 'flipLtRt.m' with following code:

```
function newIm = flipLtRt(im)
% newIm is impage im flipped from left to right

[nr,nc,np]= size(im);    % dimensions of im
newIm= zeros(nr,nc,np);  % initialize newIm with zeros
newIm= uint8(newIm);     % Matlab uses unsigned 8-bit int for color values


for r= 1:nr
    for c= 1:nc
        for p= 1:np
            newIm(r,c,p)= im(r,nc-c+1,p);
        end
    end
end
```

By applying this code:

```
I = imread('Dog.jpg');  
Dog = flipLtRt(I);  
imshow(Dog);
```

my dog image is mirrored.

It is easy for us to use this file 'flipLtRt.m' to mirror an image without actually understanding the code. If someone tells me to mirror an image, I can simply apply the code (second section) but if someone tells me to actually explain how each line of code do, I won't be able to.

Would anyone be able to explain what each line of the code actually do?
It's the 'for' part that I cannot understand properly. And what is 'np'? New position?

Comment: It's well worth learning to use the debugger, even (perhaps especially) as an absolute beginner - set a breakpoint at the beginning, call the function with your image, then step through the code (use the "step over" command) and watch the variables in the workspace and see how each piece of code changes them.

Answer (score 1):

The code iterate over the rows of the image *im*, which is represented by a matrix with *nr* rows and *np* columns, flipping:

- The 1st column with the last;
- The 2nd column with the penultimate;
- The c-th column with the nc-(c-1)th column;

You can see this column flipping at the line:

```
newIm(r,c,p)= im(r,nc-c+1,p);
```

Where:

- *r* is the row index, *nr* is the number of rows;
- *c* is the column index *nc* is the number of columns;
- *p* is color channel index (e.g.: 1=Red, 2=Green, 3=Blue);
- *np* is the number of color channels;

Comment: The for statement makes the value of the variable (e.g. *r*) change its value over a range (e.g. 1 to nr). This is used to iterate over the rows of the matrix.