# Image colour change using matlab

Tags: matlab

I am working with a piece of code below. I am still familiarizing myself with the software and code.
I have commented few lines of code.
But I am still stuck on the 'for' loop part.
Basically what I am trying to do is to try and explain what the for loop actually does in plain english.

```
for r= 1:nr
    for c= 1:nc
        if ( im(r,c,1)>180 && im(r,c,2)>180 && im(r,c,3)>180 )
            % white feather of the duck; now changing it to yellow
            newIm(r,c,1)= 225;
            newIm(r,c,2)= 225;
            newIm(r,c,3)= 0;
        else  % the rest of the picture; no change
            for p= 1:np
                newIm(r,c,p)= im(r,c,p);
            end
        end
    end
end

imshow(newIm) % displays the image
```

If I were to say:

'The code iterate over the rows of the image im, which is represented by a matrix with nr rows and np columns, where if the row index and the column index colour red, green and blue is greater than the value of 180, change the colour white to yellow; specifically row index and the column index colour red and green to the value of 255, but the blue value to 0 (null), which ultimately results colour yellow'

Would it be all right?

```
else 
   for p= 1:np
         newIm(r,c,p)= im(r,c,p);
```

But what would be the plain explanation for code shown above?
I know there is no change made to the image but I somehow can't explain how I want to. What exactly is **'for p=1:np'** mean?
If my explanation above was wrong, would you also be able to fix and add infomation if necessary?
I'm just trying to understand what it really does.

Comment: 1: `r` and `c` are constant in that loop - what do you think e.g. `x(p) = y(p)` would do? 2:`im` isn't a matrix, it's a 3-dimensional array - each 'pixel' has its 3 elements along the 3rd dimension

Comment: I think what you have written is right. The `if` statement is seeing what the colour of the pixel is. If it is white (all 3 numbers bigger than 180, then the pixel is made yellow. If not all the values are above 180 (so the pixel is not white) then the `else` part is activated, and the pixel is left unchanged in `newIm`. So the `else` just copies the pixel from the original image to the new image.

Comment: There was my previous question regards to matlap image mirroring. The guy who explained to me was clear. im here is variable isn't it? That is abbreviation of 'image'. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081237/flipping-images-using-matlab